# Windows 10: How to set program path in File Associations?

Tags: windows-10, file-association

I have two versions of R on my computer; I want to set the file association (default app) for `.Rdata` file to the older version of R. For this, I was looking to change the path of the R program used to open the `.Rdata` files, but I don't see how to do it in the "Choose default apps by file type" dialog - see the screenshot:

[image]

How can I set the program path for default openning of `.Rdata` files?

Comment: Right-click any RData file in Windows Explorer, click Open With, then Browse and choose the R `.exe` in the R folder under Program Files. Ensure that "Always Use This Program" is checked.

Comment: thanks @harrymc, but 1) for unknown reason this doesn't work for me... I will look up the 3.5.1 R .exe, but the application that is launched is still the 3.6.0 version of R! Not sure what is going on here.... 2) is there a way to look at the original program path which is set right now? This was possible in Win XP if I remember well (don't understand why they complicated it in Win 10)

Comment: Use regedit and go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rdata`.

Comment: @harrymc, ok, but there is no path there. The value is just "RWorkspace" without any path. And the directory with binaries isn't in `%PATH%`.

Comment: Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RWorkspace` and you will find the info in a sub-key.

Comment: @harrymc this finally helped, thanks! Do you want it to post it as an answer? If not I will do it.

Comment: Done as requested. Feel free to edit and append the data you found to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general procedure for finding the executable handling a given
file-extension, for example `.rdata`:

- Use `regedit` first and go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rdata`
- If the `.exe` file is specified, all is fine.
  Else note the `(Default)` value, which here was "RWorkspace"
- Continue to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RWorkspace`. The executable will be found
  in a sub-key (which is probably called `Shell`).