# Change default application for opening certain files to be a commandline application (e.g. neovim/nvim/vim)

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, neovim

For example if I have a .md file in a directory open in file explorer and I open it, it should open within neovim with syntax that generally looks like this:

```
wt nvim %
```

wt being windows terminal and % being a file path to the .md file.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can just run `wt anything`. What's the specific issue here? Adding RMB menu entry? Assigning the extension to be ran that way? What did you attemp?

Comment: I think you want tihe commands `ftype` (to create a *FileType* -- aka *ProgID*) and then `assoc` to associiate an extension with your `FileType`. So start with `ftype / ?` and `assoc /?` at the command line.

Comment: @Destroy666 Yeah I get just opening open a run prompt to do wt [command] but thats not what I want. I want to make it so when I double click a file e.g. a text file in file explorer I want it to open within neovim without me having to manually open a terminal at that location then open neovim with `nvim [file name]` Oh and this would help with stuff like lf.

Comment: You should edit your question to mention opening with default application with double click in that case, questions should be **as specific as possible**. Anyways, this is IMO a duplicate of at least a few similar questions, like https://superuser.com/questions/1456106/windows-10-how-to-set-program-path-in-file-associations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10: How to set program path in File Associations?](https://superuser.com/questions/1456106/windows-10-how-to-set-program-path-in-file-associations)

Comment: @Destroy666 I can use that method to set it up to open within the nvim executable but that will open in "console" rather than windows terminal.


Another possible solution is using the nvim-qt executable but idk how to turn off window decorations (borders) on it like i can on windows terminal by changing it to "focus mode" in settings.

I also dont know how to configure qt to use the specific font I want.

Another possible solution is to use neovide which is like GUI neovimbut i really dislike the motion blur applied to the cursor